# printing value of variable for each iteration in for loop?

Tags: python, loops

I have a code that's working the way I want it but for one thing: printing the coefficients only prints the values for the first iteration (n=2), not for the others (n=5 and 20) even for those iterations. I'm confused because the code is actually calculating the different values and plotting them properly for each iteration.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")  #ignore warnings
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from scipy.integrate import quad

#unique depending on the problem

y = lambda t: 3*t   
T = 4      #period
w = 2*np.pi/T #angular frequency
print('Angular Frequency [rad]:',w)
n_list = np.array([2,5,20])

#for loop for multiple n values:
for n in n_list:

    Bn = (2/T)*quad(lambda t: y(t)*np.sin(n*w*t), -T/2, T/2)[0]  #for odd functions  
    An = (2/T)*quad(lambda t: y(t)*np.cos(n*w*t), -T/2, T/2)[0]  #for even
    A0 = (1/T)*quad(lambda t: y(t), -T/2, T/2)[0]   #vertical shift
    print('Coefficients [V]:', 'Bn:',Bn, 'An:', An,'A0:', A0)
    y = lambda t: A0+An*np.cos(n*w*t)+Bn*np.sin(n*w*t) #total equation

    t = np.linspace(-6, 6)
    plt.plot(t,y(t))
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I think your problem is the code is waiting for the command `plt.show()` to be excuted, but while the plot window is opened, the code is on halt

Comment: ok, so how do I fix it? It still prints just the first iteration values if I place the print line after plt.show

Comment: Aside: ignoring warnings is a super bad idea. Don't ignore / squash / hide warnings, fix them!

Comment: `warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")  #ignore warnings` ??